# Got a `TypeError` when calling `WordsTable.objects.create()`

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to save some data in the database using serializer. I have created a model and a serializer but I get this error when I try to save the data. I have seen many answers but haven't come up with the solution.

I get this error:`Got a TypeError when calling WordsTable.objects.create(). This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to WordsTable.objects.create(). You may need to make the field read-only, or override the WordsTableSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.`

models.py:

```py
class WordsTable(models.Model):
    session_id = models.IntegerField(
        db_column="session_ID", blank=True, null=True
    )  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_id = models.IntegerField(
        db_column="user_ID", blank=True, null=True
    )  # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    hour = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    run_label = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    word1 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word3 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word4 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word5 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "words_table"
```

The serializer:

```py
class WordsTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WordsTable
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py:

```py
#API
@api_view(["POST"])
def save_words(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        saveserialize = WordsTableSerializer(data=request.data)
        if saveserialize.is_valid():
            saveserialize.save()
            return Response(saveserialize.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(saveserialize.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The data I'm trying to post:

```json
{
    "session_id" : 4567,
    "word1" : "Pants",
    "word2" : "Shock",
    "word3" : "Cucumber"
}
```

What do I have to add? it's the first time I use serializers so I'm a bit confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `hour` as a `models.TimeField` but the default value for the field is a date that might be the reason.
If you want to store the value of hour, You can try:

```py
hour = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.datetime.now().hour)
```

Comment: Hello; The error still appears, do you know why could this be?

Comment: Are you sure you are having exact the data you've provided is in ```request.data```

Comment: I found the issue, thanks for the help!